# How do I declare a local variable within a hotkey in AutoHotkey?

Tags: scope, autohotkey, local-variables

**TL:DR; I can't declare variables inside a hotkey as local, which means `temp` and `index` are globally accessible.**

I recently discovered that [local variables](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Locals) cannot be declared as local from within a hotkey or if they are used as parameters within a [for-loop](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/For.htm).

```
^j::
   local temp = Hello, world!  ; Error: This line does not contain a recognized action
Return

SampleFunction() {
   for local temp in myArray {  ; Error: Variable name contains an illegal character
      ; do stuff
   }
}
```

This becomes an issue with `#warn` enabled. Unless I remember to use unique variable names for each of my for loops, I run into the following error:

> **Warning: This local variable has same name as a global variable.** (Specifically: index)

For example:

```
#warn

^j::
   index = 42  ; This *index* variable is global
Return

UnrelatedFunction() {
   for index in myArray {  ; This *index* variable is local
      MsgBox % myArray[index] 
   }
}
```

In particular this becomes a problem when using imports, as variables from my own scripts often conflict with variables from my imported scripts.

Ideally, I would be able to put a local declaration before any for-loops, but as shown earlier, I'm not able to do this within hotkeys.

**Is it possible to declare a variable as local from within a hotkey?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implement my hotkeys with functions. Variables within functions have by default local scope unless they are declared `global`

```
F1::alpha(10,10)
F2::alpha(20,30)
F3::beta()


alpha(x,y)
{
   myvar := x*2 + y
}

beta()
{
   myvar := 47
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions for naming functions in scripts with only a single hotkey? Would something like `MainFucntion()` be good practice?

Comment: From https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#lib, the policy is to name the function after the file that contains it - this prevents (somewhat) namespace collisions. Which, of course, just re-exposes the namespace problem that the OP was talking about, just with function names instead of variable names :)

Comment: @DewiMorgan Seeing as my current script wasn't originally designed as a library, retrofitting my functions with underscore prefixes is going to be interesting...